# Ajax dynamically binded buttons are not working in mvc

Tags: javascript, ajax, asp.net-mvc, jquery-mobile, asp.net-mvc-2

I've Bind a div with ajax result data. Its not working after binding the content. While page load view function the controls are working. But after adding the code to the div using ajax no script is running when use any control in the populated div. The controls outside the div is working with script.

I'm using mvc 2, Please help me on this.

**ajax code**

```
 function Operation(ActionResult, mod,discid) {
            $.ajax({
                type: 'Get',
                url: ActionResult,
                data: { strDiscId: discid, PageNum: $("#hdnPagenum").val(), PageCount: $("#hdnPageCount").val(), 
                        strSearchType: $("#hidSort").val(),strSearchText:  $("#hidSearchText").val() },
                success: function (data) {
                    flag = true;
                        if (mod == "view") {

                            $("#taBody").val(data);
                        }
                        else {
                            $("#divContactsChecks").html(data);
                        }
                }
            });
        }
    });
        $("#liTitle").click(function () {
            $("#hidSort").val('TS'); //Title Sort
            Operation('LoadDisclaimers', 'Load',0);
        });
```

**server side code**

```
public string LoadDisclaimers(string strDiscId, string PageNum, string PageCount,string, strSearchType,string strSearchText)
    {
        string strTable = "";
        AdminModel objModel = new AdminModel();
        DataTable dtDisc = new DataTable();

        string strOrderBy = "";
        switch (strSearchType)
        {
            case "TS": strOrderBy = "[name]"; break;
            case "US": strOrderBy = "date_updated"; break;
            case "CS": strOrderBy = "date_created"; break;
            case "TSD": strOrderBy = "[name] desc"; break;
            case "USD": strOrderBy = "date_updated desc"; break;
            case "CSD": strOrderBy = "date_created desc"; break;
            default: strOrderBy = "[name]"; break;
        }
        using (dtDisc = objModel.GetDisclaimer(strOrderBy, Convert.ToInt16(PageNum), Convert.ToInt16(PageCount), strSearchText))
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < dtDisc.Rows.Count; i++)
            {
                string strId = dtDisc.Rows[i]["disc_id"].ToString();
                strTable += "<div class='border-bottom-line gm-pad-tb-12'>";
                strTable += "<span class='display-ib-top'><input id='ipCheck" + strId + "' type='checkbox' value='" + strId + "' class='default-checkbox' />";
                strTable += "<label for='ipCheck" + strId + "'></label></span>";
                strTable += "<div class='display-ib-top m-left25 span-45-p'>";
                strTable += "<div><span id=spTitle_" + strId + " class='blue-h1 font-arial-18'>" + dtDisc.Rows[i]["name"].ToString() + "</span></div>";
                strTable += "<div><span class='font-arial-14 display-ib-middle'>Created on : </span>";
                strTable += "<span class='display-ib-middle adm-disable font-arial-12'>" + dtDisc.Rows[i]["date_created"].ToString() + "</span></div>";
                strTable += "<div><span class='font-arial-14 display-ib-middle'>Modified on : </span>";
                strTable += "<span class='display-ib-middle adm-disable font-arial-12'>" + dtDisc.Rows[i]["date_updated"].ToString() + "</span></div>";
                strTable += "</div><div class='display-ib-middle rgt'>";
                strTable += "<span id=spViewDisc_" + strId + " class='display-ib-middle light-grey-btn large-btn'>View Details</span></div></div>";
            }
        }
        ViewData["Disclaimers"] = strTable;
        return strTable;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [.on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/) for event delegation in jQuery

```
$("#liTitle").on('click', function () {
    $("#hidSort").val('TS'); //Title Sort
    Operation('LoadDisclaimers', 'Load',0);
});
```

### EDIT

As per comment, you need to use `$("#divContactsChecks").on('click',"span[id^='spViewDisc_']", function ()` instead of `$("span[id^='spViewDisc_']").click(function ()`

Event handlers are bound only to the currently selected elements; they must exist on the page at the time your code makes the call to `.click()`.

Comment: $("#liTitle").on('click', function () { function is always working. Because it is outside the div "divContactsChecks".
 <div id="divContactsChecks">
                    <%Html.RenderPartial("ShowDisclaimers", 
ViewData["Disclaimers"]); %>
                </div>
But after loading the div with the html code  ($("#divContactsChecks").html(data); ) It is not working any span "<span id=spViewDisc_" or any checkboxes. This will work after page load.

Comment: @RageshSivakumar, which function is not woking post that code

Comment: Everything is working fine before getting the html code and bind to the div:
These are the function:

$("span[id^='spViewDisc_']").click(function () {
                $("#hidMode").val("Update");
                var curID = $(this).attr("id").split('_');
                $("#hdnDiscID").val(curID[1]);
                $('#ipTitle').val($('#spTitle_' + curID[1]).text());
                Operation("getDiscText", "view", curID[1]);
                $("#divAddDisc").show('fast');
            });
Also checkboxes are not working.

Comment: @RageshSivakumar, use `$("#divContactsChecks").on('click',"span[id^='spViewDisc_']", function ()` instead of `$("span[id^='spViewDisc_']").click(function ()`

Comment: Amazing.... Its worked. :D
Can you please tell me why $("span[id^='spViewDisc_']").click(function () is not working??

Thanks so much....

Happy coding